# Why this.setState is not a function?

Tags: react-native

I create a `<FlatList />` include `<Text />` , i want to click each of the `<Text />` can change `this.state`.

But when i click it that will show error:

```
this.setState is not a function
```

Why?

Here is my `<FlatList />`:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={() => (
            !cityArray.length ? (
              <View style={{ height: 300 }}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>
                  Show empty message...
                </Text>
              </View>) : null
          )}
          data={cityArray}
          renderItem={this.renderItem} 
          horizontal={true}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
```

Here is my `renderItem` function: `onPress` will shows the error

```
renderItem({ item }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerView}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({ test: 'test press' });
          }}
        >
          <Text>{item.cnCity}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>      
    );
  }
```

My this.state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
    this.state = { tickets: [], selectedOption: '', theaters: [], test: '' };
  }
```

I try to creat another function:

```
  testPress = () => {
    this.setState({ test: 'test function' });
  }
```

and use it like:

```
renderItem({ item }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerView}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() => {
            this.testPress();
          }}
        >
          <Text>{item.cnCity}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>      
    );
  }
```

It still shows the same error. Why? I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you want the `FlatList` to know the data change outside of the data prop, you need to set it to `extraData`, give it a try and tell me if problem exist! [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata)

Comment: Hey its quite a useful prompt. I try add `extraData={this.state}` under `data={cityArray}`, i though it will work, but still get the same error...

Comment: this here not referring to class it referring  to renderItem function

Comment: @nima_moradi Sor, i don't understand what you  mean `this here`. Would you mind explain again ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this thing 

first save a ref to `this`

```
 let context;
    class s extends Component{
         constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
        this.state = { tickets: [], selectedOption: '', theaters: [], test: '' };
        context=this;
      }

     }
```

and you it in onpress

```
  <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => {
        context.setState({ test: 'test press' });
      }}
    >
```

#### why this not work?

this in js a keyword known as context and it only depend on caller, so when we call a function from other one it will use function context that there is no State in it
solution is either bind function or save reference and sometimes you can use nameless function
 
for more info visit [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Your code is working. Thank you. But i didn't use like that before. So if i want to use `this.setState` , i must put it into some kind of react class function or i should set some variable like `let context` connect `this` . Am i right ?  Thanks for your help @nima_moradi

Comment: in js this is a special keyword in function value only depends on how the function was called, you can use bind or what i did

Comment: check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot, blessing.